# Cannot find the alias dropdown in Google Apps user creation

Tags: google-workspace

I don't know whether I have done something wrong to my Google Apps domain or something. But, I have added and verified the alias domain successfully.

However, there is no dropdown domain to select while we create a new account like it used to be before.

And the the alias domain will be automatically set to the newly created domain.

Do I have to wait for some time after adding new alias domain or did Google changed something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Answered by myself

Comment: I also meet this problem, i just added & verified new domain alias, when I add a new user there is no dropdown on the domain to select but only the primary domain. Does google already disabled this feature? Help much needed. thanks

Comment: It's easy though they had done some crazy upgrade to their systems... Anyway what I did is pretty simple.. You just upgrade to premium on trial then after fix everything you disable it back to standard package..

Answer (score 1):

A domain alias gives everyone another email address, an alias, with the new domain. For example, adding the domain alias.com as an alias to example.com, gives bob@example.com another email address at bob@alias.com. Directions for adding a domain alias are [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182079).

The behavior you are describing requires you to add another domain to your Google Apps environment, also referred to as a secondary domain. Directions for adding a domain can be found [here.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4399436)